# Buffer xrun in Alsa while ffmpeg streaming from certain sources

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, alsa, pulse-audio

I am broadcasting the audio of my desktop PC (client here onwards) using the Pulseaudio RTP module:

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp_2_camilla channels=2 format=S16BE rate=96000 sink_properties="device.description='RTP to CamillaDSP'"
load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp_2_camilla.monitor destination_ip=192.168.0.22 port=46908
```

On the receiving part is a RPi4b (server here onwards) with ffmpeg running in command-line and no Pulseaudio. I generated an sdp file from Pulseaudio debug output and used that on the client to identify the stream:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i stream_96k_s16be.sdp -f alsa hw:0,0
```

All good until now, and in may applications, the setup works perfectly except for increasingly high latency -- which I'll come to later.
Main issue is that with certain applications at the client, ffmpeg has severe buffer underruns. I hear that for each packet about half of the audio is not there and it is almost as bad as listening to static noise. This is the log when that happens:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel trace -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i stream_96k_s16be.sdp -f alsa hw:0,0 -report
ffmpeg started on 2023-02-22 at 10:12:51
Report written to "ffmpeg-20230222-101251.log"
Log level: 56
ffmpeg version 4.3.5-0+deb11u1+rpt3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1+rpt3 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --enable-sand --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'trace'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,udp,rtp'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'stream_96k_s16be.sdp'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'alsa'.
Reading option 'hw:0,0' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument trace.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url stream_96k_s16be.sdp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: stream_96k_s16be.sdp.
[NULL @ 0x557fb57720] Opening 'stream_96k_s16be.sdp' for reading
Probing sdp score:50 size:205
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] Format sdp probed with size=2048 and score=50
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: v='0'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: o='kerem 3885738296 0 IN IP4 192.168.0.###'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: s='PulseAudio RTP Stream on ke#######'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: c='IN IP4 192.168.0.###'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: t='3885738296 0'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: a='recvonly'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: m='audio 46908 RTP/AVP 127'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: a='rtpmap:127 L16/96000/2'
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] audio codec set to: pcm_s16be
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] audio samplerate set to: 96000
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] audio channels set to: 2
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sdp: a='type:broadcast'
[udp @ 0x557fb0fb60] end receive buffer size reported is 425984
[udp @ 0x557fb5ea90] end receive buffer size reported is 425984
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 205 bytes read:205 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] All info found
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] stream 0: start_time: 0 duration: NOPTS
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] format: start_time: 0 duration: NOPTS (estimate from bit rate) bitrate=3072 kb/s
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 205 bytes read:205 seeks:0 frames:1
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, sdp, from 'stream_96k_s16be.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : PulseAudio RTP Stream on ke#####
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3072 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/96000: Audio: pcm_s16be, 96000 Hz, stereo, s16, 3072 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url hw:0,0.
Applying option f (force format) with argument alsa.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: hw:0,0.
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
detected 4 logical cores
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x557fb5d1f0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/96000'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x557fb5d1f0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '96000'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x557fb5d1f0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x557fb5d1f0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x557fb5d1f0] tb:1/96000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:96000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_0 @ 0x557fb9c6e0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x557fb5ff30] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
Output #0, alsa, to 'hw:0,0':
  Metadata:
    title           : PulseAudio RTP Stream on ke######
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/96000: Audio: pcm_s16le, 96000 Hz, stereo, s16, 3072 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s16le
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.
    Last message repeated 68 times
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.peed=0.473x    
    Last message repeated 69 times
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.peed=0.466x    
    Last message repeated 69 times
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.peed=0.463x    
    Last message repeated 5 times
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sending 52 bytes of RR
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] result from ffurl_write: -5
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.
    Last message repeated 63 times
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.peed=0.463x    
    Last message repeated 68 times
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.peed=0.462x    
    Last message repeated 68 times
[alsa @ 0x557fb59ee0] ALSA buffer xrun.peed=0.462x    
    Last message repeated 14 times
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] sending 52 bytes of RR
[sdp @ 0x557fb57720] result from ffurl_write: -5
```

E.g. with Vivaldi browser I do not have the problem, yet with Rhythmbox I have the problem always. I tried combinations with following settings in ffmpeg:

```
-flags low_delay
-fflags nobuffer
-avioflags direct
-buffer_size 4096
-re
```

Some of the combinations did fix the increasingly high latency issue mentioned before, but this chopping audio with Rhythmbox and others resides. I checked Pulseaudio output latency using `$pactl list sinks` and it is moving around between 0.1ms to 2ms, and this seems consistent with whatever application is playing.
And to further clarify, my input device in Alsa is a snd-aloop loopback module, that is being captured by [CamillaDSP](https://github.com/HEnquist/camilladsp). CamillaDSP processes the capture in and plays on the USB sound card. It supports rate adjustment so I really don't think it is the culprit. If I do a speaker-test with Alsa on the server or the client, it plays a clean audio out of CamillaDSP.

Thanks already for reading and looking forward to your support.